# SQL Table Joining Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables (maintable and categorytable)

maintable records :

```
categoryCode  field2   field3

1             XXXXXX1  ACTIVE
3             XXXXXX2  ACTIVE
1             XXXXXX3  ACTIVE
1             XXXXXX4  ACTIVE
3             XXXXXX5  ACTIVE
3             XXXXXX5  NOT ACTIVE
```

categorytable records :

```
categoryCode        categoryname

1                   categoryname1
2                   categoryname2
3                   categoryname3
```

So far I have this query

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordcount,
         categoryCode AS catCode,
         categorytable.categoryname
    FROM maintable, 
         categorytable
   WHERE categorytable.categoryCode = maintable.categoryCode 
     AND maintable.field3 = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY maintable.categoryCode 
ORDER BY categorytable.categoryCode
```

with the following output

```
recordcount catCode categoryname
----------------------------------
3           1       categoryname1
2           3       categoryname3
```

But I need an output something like this (Categories with 0 records included showing a recordcount of 0):

```
recordcount catCode categoryname
3           1       categoryname1
0           2       categoryname2
2           3       categoryname3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(COUNT(maintable.categoryCode),0) AS recordcount, 
    categorytable.categoryCode AS catCode, 
    categorytable.categoryname
FROM 
    maintable 
RIGHT JOIN categorytable ON categorytable.categoryCode = maintable.categoryCode 
GROUP BY 
    categorytable.categoryCode, 
    categorytable.categoryname 
ORDER BY 
    categorytable.categoryCode
```

or, with a left join

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(COUNT(maintable.categoryCode),0) AS recordcount, 
    categorytable.categoryCode AS catCode, 
    categorytable.categoryname
FROM 
    categorytable
LEFT JOIN maintable ON categorytable.categoryCode = maintable.categoryCode 
GROUP BY 
    categorytable.categoryCode, 
    categorytable.categoryname 
ORDER BY 
    categorytable.categoryCode
```

Comment: Damn Ctrl+V! Can't it read it must paste a "LEFT" the second time? Buhhhh stupid keyboard. When will it learn?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a left join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordcount, categoryCode AS catCode, categorytable.categoryname
FROM categorytable
LEFT JOIN maintable ON categorytable.categoryCode = maintable.categoryCode 
GROUP BY maintable.categoryCode 
ORDER BY categorytable.categoryCode
```

If you don't want to reverse the table names see AlexanderMP's answer.

Comment: I bet you meant to write "RIGHT JOIN".

Comment: @AlexanderMP - It would be the same result either way.

Comment: Your query shows the same output (categories with 0 recordcount not shown)

Comment: I really don't know for sure about MySQL, but in all other RDBMS I've worked with (FirebirdSql, MSSQL, PostgreSql), this calls for RIGHT JOIN, since LEFT join will only return rows present in the `maintable`, even if they are not in `categorytable`, here is needed the other way around - rows present in `categorytable` which aren't necessarily present in `maintable`

Comment: So there are 4 types of joins: INNER JOIN (gets only records present in both tables), LEFT OUTER JOIN (gets records from first table even if not present in joined table), RIGHT OUTER JOIN (gets records from joined table even if nothing according is present in first table), and FULL OUTER JOIN (gets all rows from all tables).

Comment: @AlexanderMP - you're right. Generally I only use left join and list the tables in the order needed. Editing to reflect and +1 to your answer :)

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I haven't. I think it'll never return a zero row count. Work-arounds are possible, but I have no idea if they are needed. Still waiting for author to respond :).

Comment: No I didn't have a DB handy to setup. Otherwise I would have figured out my own was wrong!